# cakephp $this->html->link not changing location

Tags: php, cakephp, hyperlink, routes

I am using cakephp 2.2

I have routers configured to have pretty urls

html link not changing stuck on first result

the below code works and does what I want, but I am trying to use cakes way of generating links

```
<td><a href="/<?php echo $examples['somemodel']['slug'];?>"><?php echo $examples['somemodel'][slug'];?> </a></td>
```

when I do this the url name is different
but the hyper link doesn't change

```
<?php echo 
$this->Html->link($examples['model']['somename'], '/controllername/slug/' + $examples['model']['slug']);
?>
```

my results are

```
<a href =”/example1”>example1 </a> 
<a href =”/example1 ”>example2 </a> 
<a href =”/example1 ”>example3 </a> 
<a href =”/example1”>example4 </a>
```

instead of what I want it to do

```
<a href =”/example1”>example1 </a> 
<a href =”/example2”>example2 </a> 
<a href =”/example3”>example3 </a>
```

as you can see the url name is different
but the hyper link doesn't change

//router.php
    Router::connect(

```
"/example/:slug",
array('controller' => 'differentname', 'action' => 'view'),
       array( 

            'name'=>'[-A-Z0-9]+', 

           'pass' => array('slug')



          ) 

        );

Router::connectNamed(
array('/example/' => array('action' => 'view', 'controller' => 'different')),
array('default' => true, 'greedy' => true)
);      



//'view.ctp

  <?php
foreach ($example as $examples): ?>

 <?php echo 
 $this->Html->link($examples['model']['somename'], '/controllername/slug/' +     $examples['model']['slug']);
 ?>
```

results 
     example1  
     example2  
     example3  
     example4

instead of

```
   <a href =”/example1”>example1 </a> 
 <a href =”/example2”>example2 </a> 
<a href =”/example3”>example3 </a>
```

What am I missing or not getting here

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because the use of '+' as a text append operator. You need to use '.' instead.

Example:

`$this->Html->link($examples['model']['somename'], '/controllername/slug/'.$examples['model']['slug']);`

Comment: thank you that worked.  in the book it was referencing this <?php
$this->Html->link('View', '/posts/view/' + $id); I guess i miss read it

Comment: sorry for the dumb question how do i mark it as answer it? I tried clicking the answer button, but it said not enough rep to do this yet